# Heroku - how to run Schedluer addon 4x per day?

Tags: heroku, cron, scheduler

I have an app hosted on Heroku and this app need to run some task several times per day, lets say 4 times (and in the best way - I would like to set up, which hour will be the task run - eg. 1. task at 1AM, 2. at 5AM, 3. at 11AM and 4. at 8PM).

Heroku offers the addon called [Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler). Is there any way to run tasks by the time scheme above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the scheduler hourly but you'd need to check what hour it currently is via;

`[1,5,11,20].include?(Time.now.hour)`

in the task that you want to run to have it run at 1am, 5am, 11am and 8pm as per your question.